# How to create a MockMvc and a WebDriver in Spring 5

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, testing

I wrote the following simple test case to test MockMvc and the WebDriver:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration("/src/main/resources")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MvcConfig.class})
public class exampleTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mvc;
    private WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context).build();
        this.driver = MockMvcHtmlUnitDriverBuilder.webAppContextSetup(this.context).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void mvcTest() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    public void driverTest() {
        this.driver.get("http://localhost:8080/");
        assertEquals("Please log in", this.driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/h1")).getText());
    }

}
```

If I execute it, I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/SessionNotFoundException which is thrown by the MockMvcHtmlUnitBuilder in the before method. If I remove the line which throws the error and the driver test, the mvcTest is not successful because it gets a 404 instead of an 200.

So the next thing I did was removing @WebAppConfiguration("/src/main/resources") and @ContextConfiguration(classes = {MvcConfig.class}) annotations and adding @SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class) annotation. Now the mvcTest works, but if i add the code for the driver again, it still throws the SessionNotFoundException.

So my question is, how do I correctly create a MockMvc and a WebDriver in Spring 5?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem. It mentions in the Spring doc that you have to install the org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver dependency. The latest version is 2.52.0. What I did now was to add the same version of the remote driver:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.52.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.52.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I also just used the @SpringBootTest annotation, so my final test class locks something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class exampleTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mvc;
    private WebClient webClient;
    private WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context).build();
        this.webClient = MockMvcWebClientBuilder.webAppContextSetup(context, springSecurity()).build();
        this.driver = MockMvcHtmlUnitDriverBuilder.webAppContextSetup(this.context, springSecurity()).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void mvcTest() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/login"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Please log in")));
    }

    @Test
    public void clientTest() throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
        HtmlPage loginPage = webClient.getPage("http://localhost:8080/app/");
        List<DomElement> pageList = loginPage.getElementsByTagName("h1");
        DomElement page = pageList.get(0);
        String text = page.getTextContent();
        assertThat(text).isEqualTo("Please log in");
    }

    @Test
    public void driverTest() {
        driver.get("http://localhost:8080/app/");
        assertEquals("Please log in",driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/h1")).getText());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the current Spring Boot and Spring Boot Test versions you can just do the following:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MyApplicationTests {
    
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;
    
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @Autowired
    private WebDriver driver;
    
    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }
    
    @Test
    public void shouldReturnDefaultMessage() throws Exception {
        this.driver.get("http://localhost:8080/app/");
        assertEquals("Please log in",driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/h1")).getText());
        
        or
        
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/app")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string("true"));
    }
}
```